# Hide overflow with scrollbars still present?

Tags: jquery, html, css

So I have a popup box on a website that I'm creating that's about 1800px in height. Before the clicking the popup the overall document is about 2500px in height. What I want to happen is after the popup is clicked the height of the document is changed to 1800px so the user can't scroll past the popup but can still scroll down to the bottom of the popup.

I've tried setting the height of the html/body to the height of the popup and then using overflow: hidden but that removes the ability to scroll altogether. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you edit the styles for the popup? Do you have a code snippet?

Comment: To "Hide overflow with scrollbars still present" you can simply create a property like `width: 200px; height: 200px; overflow-x: scroll; overflow-y: scroll;` Create a jsfiddle demonstrating your problem.